# \ref + \inaccessible : ideas to help debug a document?

Tags: debugging, ref

I have a error in a document and I'm unable to debug it.

## The errors

At the second compilation of my document, the command `\ref{}` raises the error

> Missing control sequence inserted
>
> \inaccessible
>
> l.628 ...au paragraphe \ref{bus}

If I remove the command `\ref{bus}`, the document compiles (several times, also).

If I try to recompile after this error, I have the following error and I need to trash "aux files" in order to recompile the document.

> File ended while scanning use of @writefile

## The context

The reference "bus" points to

```
\subsection{Les bus}\label{bus}
```

The document loads many packages and I'm unable to produce a MWE. Sorry for that, but maybe someone with more knowledge of TeX can guess what is the problem.

As pointed by Ulrich, the issue comes from the redefinition of `\subsection`. Indeed, I tend to replace `\def` by `\gdef`. Here is the guilty definition.

```
% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508837/8323

\gdef\mystars{}
\gdef\myexclmarks{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}\mystars\myexclmarks\setImportance{0}\setStars{0}}

\newcounter{secstars}
\newcommand\setStars[1]{%
\gdef\mystars{}%
\ifnum#1=0%
\else
\setcounter{secstars}{0}%
\loop\edef\mystars{*\mystars}%
\stepcounter{secstars}%
\ifnum\value{secstars}<#1\repeat
\edef\mystars{\,\mystars}
\fi%
}

\newcounter{secexclmarks}
\newcommand\setImportance[1]{%
\gdef\myexclmarks{}%
\ifnum#1=0%
\else
\def\myexclmarksaux{}%
\setcounter{secexclmarks}{0}%
\loop\edef\myexclmarksaux{!\myexclmarksaux}%
\stepcounter{secexclmarks}%
\ifnum\value{secexclmarks}<#1\repeat
\gdef\myexclmarks{\,$^{\displaystyle\textbf{\myexclmarksaux}}$}
\fi%
}
```

## The aux files

After the first (successful) compilation, the aux file is

```
\relax 
\providecommand\zref@newlabel[2]{}
\catcode `:\active 
\catcode `;\active 
\catcode `!\active 
\catcode `?\active 
\providecommand\tcolorbox@label[2]{}
\select@language{french}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{french}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{french}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{french}}
\select@language{french}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{french}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{french}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{french}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }L'ordinateur...}{1}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-1}{\default{1.1\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }\page{1}\abspage{1}\mdf@pagevalue{1}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid2}{1}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid2}{4661699}{34744117}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Exemple d'ordinateurs : PC domestique, smartphone, automate programmable, plate-forme de calcul.\relax }}{1}}
\providecommand*\caption@xref[2]{\@setref\relax\@undefined{#1}}
\newlabel{ordinateurs}{{1}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }Un peu d'histoire}{1}}
\newlabel{babbage}{{2a}{2}}
\newlabel{sub@babbage}{{(a)}{a}}
\newlabel{HM1}{{2b}{2}}
\newlabel{sub@HM1}{{(b)}{b}}
\newlabel{intel-4004}{{2c}{2}}
\newlabel{sub@intel-4004}{{(c)}{c}}
\newlabel{altair-8800}{{2d}{2}}
\newlabel{sub@altair-8800}{{(d)}{d}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces \relax }}{2}}
\newlabel{photos_histoire}{{2}{2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(a)}{\ignorespaces {La machine m\IeC {\'e}canique de calcul de Babbage.}}}{2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(b)}{\ignorespaces {Havard Mark 1.}}}{2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(c)}{\ignorespaces {Microprocesseur Intel 4004 (1971)}}}{2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(d)}{\ignorespaces {Micro-ordinateur Altair 8800 (1975)}}}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}Architecture globale}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }Principaux constituants d'un ordinateur}{2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3}{\ignorespaces Vue globale d'un ordinateur.\relax }}{3}}
\newlabel{ordinateur-global}{{3}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }Branchements et connecteurs}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}Architecture interne}{3}}
\newlabel{interne}{{3}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }L'unit\IeC {\'e} centrale}{3}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4}{\ignorespaces Ensemble des principaux connecteurs de p\IeC {\'e}riph\IeC {\'e}riques externes.\relax }}{4}}
\newlabel{connecteurs}{{4}{4}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {5}{\ignorespaces Principaux constituants de l'unit\IeC {\'e} centrale.\relax }}{5}}
\newlabel{unite-centrale}{{5}{5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }Le processeur}{5}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-2}{\default{3.2\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }\page{5}\abspage{5}\mdf@pagevalue{5}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid3}{5}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid3}{4661699}{22094269}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-3}{\default{3.2\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }\page{5}\abspage{5}\mdf@pagevalue{5}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid4}{5}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid4}{4661699}{16973636}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }Les bus}{6}}
\newlabel{bus}{{3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }{6}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}D\IeC {\'e}finitions}{6}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-4}{\default{3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}\page{6}\abspage{6}\mdf@pagevalue{6}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid5}{6}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid5}{4661699}{36729600}
\newlabel{branchement-direct}{{6a}{6}}
\newlabel{sub@branchement-direct}{{(a)}{a}}
\newlabel{branchement-bus}{{6b}{6}}
\newlabel{sub@branchement-bus}{{(b)}{b}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {6}{\ignorespaces Diff\IeC {\'e}rentes possibilit\IeC {\'e}s pour communiquer avec le processeur.\relax }}{6}}
\newlabel{bus-interet}{{6}{6}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(a)}{\ignorespaces {Branchement direct\newline Le processeur a 16 pattes}}}{6}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(b)}{\ignorespaces {Branchement par bus\newline Le processeur n'a que 6 pattes}}}{6}}
\newlabel{bus-parallele}{{7a}{6}}
\newlabel{sub@bus-parallele}{{(a)}{a}}
\newlabel{bus-serie}{{7b}{6}}
\newlabel{sub@bus-serie}{{(b)}{b}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {7}{\ignorespaces Exemple de types de bus\relax }}{6}}
\newlabel{type-ports}{{7}{6}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(a)}{\ignorespaces {Bus~parall\IeC {\`e}le\newline (Port~IDE~pour~les~disques~durs)}}}{6}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(b)}{\ignorespaces {Bus~s\IeC {\'e}rie \newline (Port~USB)}}}{6}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {8}{\ignorespaces \relax }}{7}}
\newlabel{bus-interne-extension}{{8}{7}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-5}{\default{3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}\page{7}\abspage{7}\mdf@pagevalue{7}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid6}{7}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid6}{4661699}{29159213}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .2}Principe de fonctionnement}{7}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {9}{\ignorespaces Sch\IeC {\'e}ma repr\IeC {\'e}sentant les bus de donn\IeC {\'e}es et d'adresses, reliant le processeur aux p\IeC {\'e}riph\IeC {\'e}riques.\relax }}{7}}
\newlabel{bus-donnees-adresses}{{9}{7}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-6}{\default{3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .2}\page{8}\abspage{8}\mdf@pagevalue{8}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid7}{8}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid7}{4661699}{44368859}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {10}{\ignorespaces Tous les p\IeC {\'e}riph\IeC {\'e}riques peuvent voir les donn\IeC {\'e}es, mais seuls ceux appel\IeC {\'e}s par le bus d'adresse r\IeC {\'e}agissent.\relax }}{8}}
\newlabel{mafia}{{10}{8}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-7}{\default{3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .2}\page{8}\abspage{8}\mdf@pagevalue{8}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid8}{8}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid8}{4661699}{16354796}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {11}{\ignorespaces Quelque part dans l'ordinateur d'un professeur de fran\IeC {\c c}ais...\relax }}{9}}
\newlabel{mafia-pilotes}{{11}{9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }Les m\IeC {\'e}moires}{9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}Les m\IeC {\'e}moires... en g\IeC {\'e}n\IeC {\'e}ral}{9}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-8}{\default{3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}\page{9}\abspage{9}\mdf@pagevalue{9}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid9}{9}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid9}{4661699}{25876282}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-9}{\default{3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}\page{9}\abspage{9}\mdf@pagevalue{9}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid10}{9}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid10}{4661699}{15790298}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-10}{\default{3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}\page{9}\abspage{9}\mdf@pagevalue{9}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid11}{9}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid11}{4661699}{9050292}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {12}{\ignorespaces Stockage des donn\IeC {\'e}es bit par bit, organis\IeC {\'e} en case-m\IeC {\'e}moire.\relax }}{10}}
\newlabel{cases-memoires}{{12}{10}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {13}{\ignorespaces Technologie de stockage des donn\IeC {\'e}es.\relax }}{10}}
\newlabel{technologie}{{13}{10}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(a)}{\ignorespaces {Carte du champ magn\IeC {\'e}tique \IeC {\`a} la surface d'un disque dur}}}{10}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(b)}{\ignorespaces {Sillons microscopiques grav\IeC {\'e}s dans un CD}}}{10}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(c)}{\ignorespaces {Circuit int\IeC {\'e}gr\IeC {\'e} de m\IeC {\'e}moire RAM (volatile)}}}{10}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-11}{\default{3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}\page{10}\abspage{10}\mdf@pagevalue{10}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid12}{10}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid12}{4661699}{11945793}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .2}Les m\IeC {\'e}moires dans l'ordinateur}{10}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {paragraph}{$\bullet $ Organisation :}{10}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-12}{\default{3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .2}\page{11}\abspage{11}\mdf@pagevalue{11}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid13}{11}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid13}{4661699}{41095701}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {14}{\ignorespaces Diff\IeC {\'e}rents types de m\IeC {\'e}moires dans un ordinateur.\relax }}{11}}
\newlabel{type-memoires-ordi}{{14}{11}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {paragraph}{$\bullet $ Adressage m\IeC {\'e}moire de la m\IeC {\'e}moire vive:}{11}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {15}{\ignorespaces Illustration d'un stockage de donn\IeC {\'e}es par adressage, sur le bus-syst\IeC {\`e}me.\relax }}{12}}
\newlabel{mafia-memoire}{{15}{12}}
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{12}}
```

After the second (and unsuccessful) compilation, the aux file is

```
\relax 
\providecommand\zref@newlabel[2]{}
\catcode `:\active 
\catcode `;\active 
\catcode `!\active 
\catcode `?\active 
\providecommand\tcolorbox@label[2]{}
\select@language{french}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{french}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{french}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{french}}
\select@language{french}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{french}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{french}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{french}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }L'ordinateur...}{1}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-1}{\default{1.1\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }\page{1}\abspage{1}\mdf@pagevalue{1}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid2}{1}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid2}{4661699}{34744117}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Exemple d'ordinateurs : PC domestique, smartphone, automate programmable, plate-forme de calcul.\relax }}{1}}
\providecommand*\caption@xref[2]{\@setref\relax\@undefined{#1}}
\newlabel{ordinateurs}{{1}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }Un peu d'histoire}{1}}
\newlabel{babbage}{{2a}{2}}
\newlabel{sub@babbage}{{(a)}{a}}
\newlabel{HM1}{{2b}{2}}
\newlabel{sub@HM1}{{(b)}{b}}
\newlabel{intel-4004}{{2c}{2}}
\newlabel{sub@intel-4004}{{(c)}{c}}
\newlabel{altair-8800}{{2d}{2}}
\newlabel{sub@altair-8800}{{(d)}{d}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces \relax }}{2}}
\newlabel{photos_histoire}{{2}{2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(a)}{\ignorespaces {La machine m\IeC {\'e}canique de calcul de Babbage.}}}{2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(b)}{\ignorespaces {Havard Mark 1.}}}{2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(c)}{\ignorespaces {Microprocesseur Intel 4004 (1971)}}}{2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(d)}{\ignorespaces {Micro-ordinateur Altair 8800 (1975)}}}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}Architecture globale}{2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }Principaux constituants d'un ordinateur}{2}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3}{\ignorespaces Vue globale d'un ordinateur.\relax }}{3}}
\newlabel{ordinateur-global}{{3}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }Branchements et connecteurs}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}Architecture interne}{3}}
\newlabel{interne}{{3}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }L'unit\IeC {\'e} centrale}{3}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4}{\ignorespaces Ensemble des principaux connecteurs de p\IeC {\'e}riph\IeC {\'e}riques externes.\relax }}{4}}
\newlabel{connecteurs}{{4}{4}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {5}{\ignorespaces Principaux constituants de l'unit\IeC {\'e} centrale.\relax }}{5}}
\newlabel{unite-centrale}{{5}{5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }Le processeur}{5}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-2}{\default{3.2\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }\page{5}\abspage{5}\mdf@pagevalue{5}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid3}{5}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid3}{4661699}{22094269}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-3}{\default{3.2\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }\page{5}\abspage{5}\mdf@pagevalue{5}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid4}{5}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid4}{4661699}{16973636}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }Les bus}{6}}
\newlabel{bus}{{3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }{6}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}D\IeC {\'e}finitions}{6}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-4}{\default{3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}\page{6}\abspage{6}\mdf@pagevalue{6}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid5}{6}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid5}{4661699}{36729600}
\newlabel{branchement-direct}{{6a}{6}}
\newlabel{sub@branchement-direct}{{(a)}{a}}
\newlabel{branchement-bus}{{6b}{6}}
\newlabel{sub@branchement-bus}{{(b)}{b}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {6}{\ignorespaces Diff\IeC {\'e}rentes possibilit\IeC {\'e}s pour communiquer avec le processeur.\relax }}{6}}
\newlabel{bus-interet}{{6}{6}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(a)}{\ignorespaces {Branchement direct\newline Le processeur a 16 pattes}}}{6}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(b)}{\ignorespaces {Branchement par bus\newline Le processeur n'a que 6 pattes}}}{6}}
\newlabel{bus-parallele}{{7a}{6}}
\newlabel{sub@bus-parallele}{{(a)}{a}}
\newlabel{bus-serie}{{7b}{6}}
\newlabel{sub@bus-serie}{{(b)}{b}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {7}{\ignorespaces Exemple de types de bus\relax }}{6}}
\newlabel{type-ports}{{7}{6}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(a)}{\ignorespaces {Bus~parall\IeC {\`e}le\newline (Port~IDE~pour~les~disques~durs)}}}{6}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(b)}{\ignorespaces {Bus~s\IeC {\'e}rie \newline (Port~USB)}}}{6}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {8}{\ignorespaces \relax }}{7}}
\newlabel{bus-interne-extension}{{8}{7}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-5}{\default{3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}\page{7}\abspage{7}\mdf@pagevalue{7}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid6}{7}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid6}{4661699}{29159213}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .2}Principe de fonctionnement}{7}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {9}{\ignorespaces Sch\IeC {\'e}ma repr\IeC {\'e}sentant les bus de donn\IeC {\'e}es et d'adresses, reliant le processeur aux p\IeC {\'e}riph\IeC {\'e}riques.\relax }}{7}}
\newlabel{bus-donnees-adresses}{{9}{7}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-6}{\default{3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .2}\page{8}\abspage{8}\mdf@pagevalue{8}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid7}{8}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid7}{4661699}{44368859}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {10}{\ignorespaces Tous les p\IeC {\'e}riph\IeC {\'e}riques peuvent voir les donn\IeC {\'e}es, mais seuls ceux appel\IeC {\'e}s par le bus d'adresse r\IeC {\'e}agissent.\relax }}{8}}
\newlabel{mafia}{{10}{8}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-7}{\default{3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .2}\page{8}\abspage{8}\mdf@pagevalue{8}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid8}{8}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid8}{4661699}{16354796}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {11}{\ignorespaces Quelque part dans l'ordinateur d'un professeur de fran\IeC {\c c}ais...\relax }}{9}}
\newlabel{mafia-pilotes}{{11}{9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax }Les m\IeC {\'e}moires}{9}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}Les m\IeC {\'e}moires... en g\IeC {\'e}n\IeC {\'e}ral}{9}}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-8}{\default{3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}\page{9}\abspage{9}\mdf@pagevalue{9}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid9}{9}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid9}{4661699}{25876282}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-9}{\default{3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}\page{9}\abspage{9}\mdf@pagevalue{9}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid10}{9}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid10}{4661699}{15790298}
\zref@newlabel{mdf@pagelabel-10}{\default{3.4\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax .1}\page{9}\abspage{9}\mdf@pagevalue{9}}
\savepicturepage{pgfid11}{9}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid11}{4661699}{9050292}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {12}{\ignorespaces Stockage des donn\IeC {\'e}es bit par bit, organis\IeC {\'e} en case-m\IeC {\'e}moire.\relax }}{10}}
\newlabel{cases-memoires}{{12}{10}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {13}{\ignorespaces Technologie de stockage des donn\IeC {\'e}es.\relax }}{10}}
\newlabel{technologie}{{13}{10}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline{(a)}{\ignorespaces {Carte du champ magn\IeC {\'e}tique \IeC {\`a} la surface d'un disque dur}}}{10}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {subfig
```

Comment: Is this the only subsection for which you use a label? The other labels all seem to be sections or some sort of subfigures (like `sub@intel-4004`). Can you reference other subsections successfully? The number in the label (`3.3\gdef {}\relax \gdef {}\relax `) looks rather strange, maybe there is an issue with the way subsection numbers are defined in your document. Without code it is almost impossible to tell, though - if you could try making an MWE it would help a lot.

Comment: Your document (or the class you're using) has a faulty definition for `\thesubsection`. What it is can only be conjectured.

Comment: In her document [Creating a LaTeX Minimal Example](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/minexample-a4.pdf) Dr. Nicola Talbot describes the method of "hacking down" for obtaining minimal examples which reproduce inscrutable errors. Perhaps you can create a backup of your work and then try that approach.

Comment: this is a classic "fragile command in a moving argument" error but you are not supposed to get one of those from the fragment shown so it is rather hard to say anything. surely you can make a document that only has that `\subsection` and if it still errors remove packages from the preamble if removing them does not make the error go, then post the resulting document. It's _much_ easier for you to debug this than anyone else

Comment: probably unrelated but never do `\ifnum#1=0%` it will cause the `\else` clause to be seen _before_ the test is made. (remove the `%`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: thanks. TeX is such an obscure language! I would love to understand it a little better.

Comment: Um. The first person who pointed this out is egreg. He did so in a comment while I was still typing my answer.

Comment: As after your edit, there now is a reference to the question [Different styles for sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508837/8323), I wrote [an answer to that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509384/118714).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `\mystars` to be a fragile command (it uses multiple internal definitions) use  `\protect\mystars` or define it to be robust by using

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\setStars
```

instead of

```
\newcommand\setStars
```

similarly your other definition.

Comment: Thanks! I have to say that this is chinese for me but I will do the changes. It works!

Comment: @Colas https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands/4747#4747